# Downloading email attachment using Java EWS API running from Weblogic Server (Java Embedding - Oracle 11g)

Tags: java, oracle, unix, weblogic, exchangewebservices

I am trying to use the Java EWS API to download email attachment from Outlook. My requirement is as follows

- To connect to the mailbox
- Search for a folder named "Test"
- Inside the test folder search for a Mail with a pattern matching subject and Body
- If found , check the mail to have attachments
- If any, download the attachment to a local path.

The program is working as expected when running as a standalone java program. The program is able to download the attachment to the mentioned UNIX path.

```
try {
    //Load attachment contents into a file.
    fileAttachment.load("/pathinunixbox/"+fileAttachment.getName());
    System.out.println("Attachment Downloaded");
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

But I am getting the below exception when running the above code from Web Logic server.

Exception:

> `The request failed. Precondition for readText is nextEvent().getTypeEventType() == START_ELEMENT`

Please correct me if am doing anything wrong there. I have also compared the loading of jars between Web Logic and java program running from UNIX box. The jars loaded in the same manner.

Comment: Email attachment issue set aside, Are you able to write a simple file to the server?

Comment: Yes we are able to write files of any format to the server from java program running in weblogic server.